# Freedom of speech

Tags: political-philosophy

Is freedom of speech desired? According to the first amendment in US, there is an implied meaning that the individual has the right to say anything he wants without the need to worry about the government limiting his speech.(I believe this is also why President Trump is unable to do anything about the hate comments and negative news about him). This means that there will be implications that an individual has the freedom to offend whoever he wants (as he is able to say anything he wants). Doesn't this spread hate and tension between people? If so, why does the US government not want to amend the first amendment?

'Freedom is the right to tell people what they do not want to hear'
I cannot really remember where i heard this quote, but this quote really speaks volume. If we really do give people freedom of speech doesnt it also mean we are giving individuals the power to create conflicts and hate ?

To sum up, my question is 'Is it really necessary to have freedom of speech in a society, especially in a globalizing economy where there are more interactions between different races and religion'.

Comment: Because this already has checks and balances.  One still does not have the right to incite violence or to commit harassment or verbal assault, which all remain crimes.  And that means that, in reality, one cannot offend whoever one wants, at least not severely, nor can one say things that purposely create severe hostility or convey credible threats.  To be protected by the 1st Amendment, the purpose of the speech needs to be *as speech, to convey thoughts, feelings or information* and not *as violence or incitement, to create a hostile environment*

Comment: The current permissive consensus developed historically, for a long time Postmaster General had authority to essentially censor "obscenities" in print until the Supreme Court took it away in 1957, see [Comstock Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comstock_laws). The usual explanation is that long experience confirmed that the benefits of free speech in curtailing government's ideological pressures and corruption far outweigh the discomforts caused by "offensive" speech. An added benefit is avoiding hopeless debates over what should or should not be seen as "offensive".

Comment: The important thing to remember about any freedom is that it's as much a responsibility as a right. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should* and the principles of 'quiet enjoyment' still apply. Guns are legal in the USA too, but it's still a criminal act to murder someone with one. Guns and Voices can be used for effective change, or as weapons. The former is not an issue; it's only when you start to hurt others with either tool that it becomes a problem and where responsibility must be accepted for the consequences.

Comment: please make the title of your question a question, it will help attract quality answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the first admendment [sic] in US, an individual has the right to say anything he wants

According to the first amendment, the US Congress does not have the right to abridge freedom of speech. It explicitly does not say that individuals have the right to say what they want. Also, it has never been taken to mean that and a number of exemptions have been determined by the US Supreme Court over the years.

> This also implies that he has the freedom to offend whoever he wants

No it doesn't although it's probably fair to say that most attempts to legislate against giving offence have been struck down.

> Doesnt [sic] this spread hate and tension between people?

No. One can argue that a different interpretation than is current may reduce the amount of public hate speech. Given that a number of countries do make hate speech illegal, it's not entirely obvious that this has led to less hate and tension.

Comment: The last sentence is false.  The First Amendment is part of the Bill of Rights and could be edited by adding another amendment.

Comment: @jobermark You are completely correct. Thank you for pointing that out, I've removed the offending paragraph. The question had already removed reference to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, freedom of speech is desirable and necessary. The First Amendment to the US Constitution prevents the government from abridging freedom of speech. However, there are laws against defamation, breach of national security, contempt of court, etc. So the First Amendment is not absolute. The First Amendment could itself be amended to forbid hate speech. The UK has laws against hate speech despite the unwritten constitutional presumption of the negative right to freedom of speech. Abridgement of this negative right to prevent hate speech is desirable and necessary, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the discussion about "free speech" is almost never actually about the freedom to say anything you are physically able to say, but it's really about the ability to speak in public, to the public and to have the ability to influence the public (and who is allowed to do so and who isn't).

So there are themes of personal expression (art, music, poetry, etc.), there are themes of personal believes (religions, ideologies, philosophical view points, etc.), there are themes of power (the ability to insert your opinion, to spread your narrative, to affirm or to veto, to gather or break support for something, to amplify or silence etc.), there are themes of the common knowledge and the private sphere and so much more.

And as you might have realized some of these themes or even elements in these themes are mutually exclusive. And as such it is a topic of continuous and intense political debate where to draw and what values to prioritize in that.

Like suppose everyone has the right to free speech and free speech is really as simple as anything that can come out of your mouth is allowed to come out of your mouth. Then whoever screams the loudest is heard and the rest is drowned in noise. So while a universal right in theory in practice it would be a privilege that is only usable by some.

Or let's assume you use the ability to speak to make threats and to intimidate people in order to push them out of the public sphere and thus invalidate their ability to speak in public. Again universal right in theory, privilege in practice.

So what part of "free speech" do you focus on? The theoretically absolute and universal right or the fact that when people want to make use of it they have a very different experience and for probably most people it's heavily restricted already even if that is not explicitly part of the law. So both proponents and opponents of this practice could refer to "free speech" as their demand yet might mean very different things with it.

So usually the "free speech" doesn't exist in a vacuum, but there is the explicit (laws, rights, constitutions) or implicit (unwritten laws, agreements, mutual consent) assumption that in order to have free speech you have to be able to speak and in order to speak you have to be alive and don't have to fear death for speaking out.

So usually laws protecting the individual to at least preserve the ability to speak, have priority over free speech. So murder contracts, threats, stalking, insults, defamation, credible assertions of denying or not applying existing rights etc. are fully or partially exempt from the protection of "free speech". which again for the perpetrators constitutes a restriction of free speech while for the rest is the requirement to be able to make any use of free speech at all.

Another point worth noting might be that the idea of speech as (physically) harmless (compared to idk a punch in the face) has since been revised and words can hurt, sometimes way more than sticks and stones and emotional bandage is still underdeveloped so the healing process of physical wounds might even be easier.

So no the point of free speech usually is not to be able to offend other people just because you like to and have them take it stoically or begrudgingly because they can't defend themselves against your assault because you have legal permission to do so.
That is at least if you want it to be a practically usable universal right and not just a privilege for assholes.

That being said with all these downsides and needs for limitation to even have it in the first place (as a universal right), there are nonetheless a lot of upsides to it as well. Like the ability to communicate with each other and to express one's ideas freely also allows common knowledge to grow, ads more perspectives to the story and allows people to identify and workaround pitfalls of social interaction that might otherwise lead to miscommunication and unnecessary conflict. The ability to have your own ideas, to explore them, to share them, to discuss them and so on can both have lots of advantages for the individual (who is no longer censored and devalued by the rest but now able to work together with others to achieve more than they could have dreamed) as well as for society which can be more stable, broad and effective if different perspectives come together.

Without free expression the societal narrative would be exclusive to one group (big or small) and the rest would see themselves in opposition to that which can create tension and even violent rebellions, while the free exchange of ideas can defuse that and lead to something more productive.

So sometimes it might even be worth listening to ideas that you don't agree with as one could still learn something from it and if it's just how not to do something and what common fallacies are in order to work on that.

So it's actually an ambivalent value that comes with priorities in terms of what people try to accomplish with it and what that is and where the lines a drawn because of that is not so much a question of mathematical logic and scientific rigor but of preferences and the political process figuring out which preferences should take priority.